# Get a MAX number in a certain period from a rrd file

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I have an `rrd` file in which `cpu average loads` are stored.

I would like to know the `Maximum Load` during a certain period; let's assume within a day.

I wrote:

```
rrdtool fetch test.rrd MAX -r 300 -e 1364712300 -s -1h
```

I got so many MAX numbers, so I have to write more code to get the actual maximum number.

My question is: Can I just write a simple command line to get this MAX number?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a single number, try

```
rrdtool graph x -s -1h -e 1364712300 \ 
   DEF:v=test.rrd:ds1:MAX VDEF:vm=v,MAXIMUM PRINT:vm:%lf
```

this will print a single number on STDOUT. No graph will be created
since you did not use any graphing instructions.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful, but what is the second parameter "x" meant for?  I'm using RRDtool 1.3.8 and I had to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you the max for every 5 minute period over your specified time range.  Try setting the `-r 3600` for a 1 hour max, or `-r 86400` for a 24 hour max.

You can verify this by looking at the timestamps given to you with the output.